# How can I get assigned products in a category without using soap API

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-enterprise

I want to get assigned products in a category with product positions in a category without using SOAP API.I don't want to use `$proxy->call($sessionId, 'catalog_category.assignedProducts'` .I am making a single file in magento folder for API.any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The call

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId)->getProductsPosition()
```

will give you an array where the array keys are the product IDs and the values are the position values for those products within that category.