# Getting products position while using flat tables

Tags: category, flat-catalog

Regarding the answer from Vinai here https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/5775/199 I have one follow-up question:

How can I get the ProductPosition array when I use flat category tables?

In my system configuration I use these settings:

```
Catalog -> Frontend -> Use Flat Catalog Category = yes
Catalog -> Frontend -> Use Flat Catalog Product  = yes
```

When I use `getProductsPosition()` I receive the following:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method  Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Category_Flat::getProductsPosition() in [...]/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Category.php on line 318
```

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should work.

```
$categoryId = '46'; //replace with your own
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId);
$positions = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/category')->getProductsPosition($category);
```

This ignores the 'Flat categories' flag. It goes directly to the category resource model.

You can even skip the category loading for performance. and just pass as parameter an object that has an `id` parameter.

```
$categoryId = '46'; //replace with your own
$category = new Varien_Object(array('id'=>$categoryId));
$positions = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/category')->getProductsPosition($category);
```

Comment: Thank you. This works in general :-)
But I still have a problem left. Now the resetting of the product positions does not work as it did while using non-flat category tables. Do you know why?
`$categoryId = 273; 
        $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId);
        $positions = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/category')->getProductsPosition($category);

        print_r($positions);

        $positions[1859] = 8;
        print_r($positions);
        $category->setPostedProducts($positions);
        $category->save();`

Sorry for the chaotic formatting :-/

Comment: btw I really like the Varien_Object approach. Great stuff :-)

Comment: I know...There is a way of saving the positions also. Unfortunately the `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Category::_saveCategoryProducts` is protected and cannot be called from anywhere. But you can create your own class that extends `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Category` add a method to it that is a wrapper for `_saveCategoryProducts` and call the wrapper method in your code. *where there's a will there's a way*

Comment: I don't think that `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Category::_saveCategoryProducts` is the key here. My approach is that you use the `setPostedProducts` method on a category object and then use `save()`. 
Like I said before it already worked. But unfortunately it only works when not using flat category setting. I just tried and checked when `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Category::_saveCategoryProducts` is called. It is only called when not using flat categories so overwriting would not work or am I missing something?

Comment: You are missing something. Let's say you have class `SomeClass sxtends Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Category` with a method: `public function saveProductRelation($category){return $this->_saveCategoryProducts($category)}`. $now you can save the products like this: `$category = new Varien_Object(array('id'=>$categoryId)); $category->setPostedProducts($positions); $category->setProdyctsPosition($oldPositions);//set the old positions $myClass = new SomeClass(); $myClass->saveProductRelation($category);`  Sorry for the code format.

Comment: Thank you Marius. This seems to be complicated (for me). What about Magento Backend itself? It seems, the backend is able to save the product positions successfully, even with flat categories enabled. 
But I wasn't able to find the code yet.

Comment: The backend does not use flat categories. You can try to simulate that you are using the backend when saving a category by calling this before `Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage::getModel('core/store')->load(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID));`. But I'm almost sure there is more to this.

Comment: Does this mean, as long as I start the process as a (Magento) cronjob, I don't have any problems because it will run in the backend environment? Please say yes! ;-)

Comment: Most probably "yes! ;-)"