# Re-indexing issue

Tags: indexing

I am using CE 1.8 and facing re-indexing issue.

While re-indexing from the Magento Admin Panel sometimes we get errors like “An error occurred while saving the URL rewrite” or “cannot initialize indexer process”.

Any help would be appreciable

Comment: Which OS do you use?

Comment: I am using Linux x86-64

Comment: have you tried reindexing using `Terminal`?

Comment: Yes, i did and get same error message..

Comment: [See Here](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/8331/product-flat-data-reindexing-getting-cannot-initialize-the-indexer-process)

Comment: @dh47 except this is URL rewrite, not flat product. Do you have configurable products? How many products in your site and how many records in URL rewrite?

Comment: 1. we have disabled flat catalog 2. 850 configurable products and each products having around 9 simple products

Comment: Try to empty core_url_rewrite table via PHPMyAdmin and reindex again, backup your DB first.

Comment: @AbhishekGupta were you able to solve this issue? If so, how?