# Call to undefined method Category_Flat::getProductsPosition Model/Category.php on line 330

Tags: php, category, flat-catalog

We are seeing an error in cron `PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Category_Flat::getProductsPosition() in app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Category.php on line 330`. Using Magento 1.9.0.1

And I don't understand why this is happening? I was reading [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/8042/getting-products-position-while-using-flat-tables). But does it mean one needs to check the flat category flag before calling this function? And still what is the cause of the error? (we saw it first after SUPEE updates and extension updates)

```
public function getProductsPosition()
    {
        if (!$this->getId()) {
            return array();
        }

        $array = $this->getData('products_position');
        if (is_null($array)) {
            $array = $this->getResource()->getProductsPosition($this);
            $this->setData('products_position', $array);
        }
        return $array;
    }
```

Comment: Please re indexing in admin side